# Oracle SQL, Looking for ideas on a constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have a table with Class, Teacher, and Leader rows,

Class and Teacher are Numbers, and Leader is a Boolean (really just a Char(1))

The table represents a relationship between teachers and classes.

A class can have many teachers, or a teacher many classes.

I need to make a constraint or check so that for each distinct class, one, and only one of the rows it occurs in must have Leader as true.

Eg.

```
Teacher |  Class | Leader
   1    |    1   |  True
   2    |    1   |  False
   2    |    2   |  True
```

Would be accepted, as each distinct class, has one row in which it occurs having a Leader value of true, but no more than one row.

Would appreciate if anyone could offer up an idea on how to represent this as a constraint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy enough to create a function-based index that enforces the "no more than one leader" portion of the constraint

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX one_leader_per_class
    ON your_table_name( (CASE WHEN leader = 'Y' 
                              THEN class
                              ELSE null
                          END) );
```

Unfortunately, it's not so easy to create a declarative constraint that enforces the requirement that each class has a leader.  The only declarative way I'm aware of to do that would be to create a materialized view that aggregates the data by class, set that materialized view to `REFRESH FAST` and create a constraint on the materialized view that ensures that the `NUM_LEADERS` column in the materialized view is always 1.  That requires that you create an appropriate materialized view log which adds overhead to DML on the table.  It also means that the constraint won't be violated until you commit which can be problematic if your applications aren't written to assume that commit can ever fail.

Comment: This looks promising, my class technically hasn't been taught functions yet, but it'll be interesting to see if it's accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding a constraint consider modeling the relationship in a different way.

As there is one-to-one relationship between class & leader
The easiest way I can see to achieve your desired results would be to store the leader (class_teacher_id) with the class record. You will need to add a unique surrogate key (class_teacher_id) to your many-to-many table (class_teacher), then you can  drop the leader boolean column.

If it is possible to have a class without a leader then simply allow the learderid to be nullable
and of course don't forget create foreign key constraints to enforce referential integrity between the class.leaderid and the new class_teacher.class_teacher_id.

Comment: I suspect that a class should be able to exist without an assigned teacher, to avoid update anomalies. Consider the situation where a class has one teacher (leader by implication) who one day is no longer able to teach and no replacement is immediately available. Your proposal would mean the class would cease to exist.

Comment: I too would expect the OP to use a foreign key. To clarify, I expect the rules to be: a) a class has zero or more teachers; b) every class with teachers has exactly one leader. So the relationship class to leader is 1:0..1 but is a consequence of the above rules rather than being a rule in itself. If you make your `leaderid` column nullable then rule b) above is not enforced.

Comment: Class And Teacher are there own tables, this table just uses a numeric foreign key to represent the many to many relationship between the two tables. It is only possible to have a class without leaders, if the class has no teachers.

Comment: cool, then you should only use this table to model the many to many relationship. To model the leaders drop the true false column, and add the leader id to class.

Comment: "only use this table to model the many to many relationship" -- would violate the principle of orthogonal design (POOD) because the same relationship 'teacher teaches class' is modelled in two tables.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing the column `is_Leader` (Boolean) column to `leadership_rank` (Integer), create a compound unique constraint on `(Teacher, Class leadership_rank)`. Then change the semantics slightly so that each teacher gets a unique random/incrementing/meaningful integer value. Then the declared leader for the class is the teacher where `leadership_rank = 1` (or perhaps the lowest rank for the group, to make things a little more flexible), perhaps using a view.

Comment: How do you enforce the class must have 1 leader constraint ?

Comment: @Kevin Burton: by changing the semantics so that the considered leader for the class is the teacher with the lowest `leadership_rank` for that class (and making `leadership_rank` not nullable, of course).

Comment: @KevinBurton: if the semantics are that the leader is the teacher where `leadership_rank = 1` then this could be done by adding a further column for the `class_teacher_tally` and then a constraint `CHECK (leadership_rank <= class_teacher_tally)`, using `MERGE` to change all `class_teacher_tally` values when adding/removing teachers from the class.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to create a table, called `Leader` with:

```
CREATE TABLE Leader
( Class
, Teacher
, PRIMARY KEY (Class)
, FOREIGN KEY (Class, Teacher)
    REFERENCES ClassTeacher (Class, Teacher)
) ;
```

and drop the ClassTeacher.Leader column.

Comment: This is probably the most pragmatic design, however it fails to enforce the rule that every class with teachers has at least one leader.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for a class assignment, and we are not allowed to add additional tables

Comment: AFAIK, this kind of strict constraints (`1::1` and `1::n` instead of `1::0..1` and `1::0..n`) cannot be done using DDL statements only.

Answer (score 0):

To enforces the requirement that each class has a leader you can use a Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tc
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON table_name
DECLARE
 v_res NUMBER;
BEGIN
  select count(*) 
  into v_res 
  from (
        select class from table_name
        minus
        select class from table_name where leader = 'Y'
        )
  ;

   if v_res > 0 
   then 
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'each class must have a leader'); 
   end if; 
END;
/
```